# Executing multiple commands from a batch script on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using the below bat script on Windows. The first line of my batch script executes a jar that starts by printing a menu prompt within the shell. I'd like the subsequent lines of the script to be used as input while executing in the jar (for example, to choose the first menu option, then input a users first name, then a users last name).

I tried the Windows **call** and **start** commands, but either didn't use the right options or was doing something wrong since I've always ended up receiving the "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error for each subsequent line in the script.

**test.bat**
java -classpath %LIBRARY_PATH% sample.Test
1
FName
LName

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your inputs in a separate file and than redirect your program to read inputs from the file like this:

test.bat

`[command] < [file]`

`[command]` would be your command to launch the java program and `[file]` would be the full path to the file containing rest of the inputs.

Comment: The issue I seem to be having with both of these solutions is that each echo or line the text file is used as input for the menu. Meaning, I get invalid input errors for all subsequent lines, because first name doesn't map to a numerical option in the menu. Is there a flag I need to set or a way I should format the file? Perhaps the text shouldn't be broken out by new lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
(
  echo 1
  echo FName
  echo LName
) | java -classpath %LIBRARY_PATH% sample.Test
```

Be careful with what you echo, since there are some special cases.

Comment: It looks like a space is added to the end of each string that I echo, so I can't even select a menu option using the first echo. Error: Enter Choice: error trying to read your choice!
Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 "

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce those superfluous spaces. (I didn't realise they existed before because the test I had used ignored them.) I guess it must be some sort of idiosyncrasy of the command processor.